# adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory has no effect

Tags: swift, fonts

On my label I am setting `.adjustsFonForContentSizeCategory = false` but it has no effect on **not** scaling the font. I am setting up my font and label like this

```swift
let font = UIFont(name: "MyFont", size: size) //1
let scaledFont = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: font) //2
let label = UILabel() //3
label.font = scaledFont //4
label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = false //5
```

And I expect that without line 5 the fonts should not be scaling by default but in my case they are. And even when I set `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = false` the fonts are still scaling.

According to the documentation the behaviour should be **not scaling** by default and only when `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory` is set to `true` the fonts should be allowed to scale.

Now I can only disable scaling by not using scaled font.

Comment: So, just don't set the value to false?

Comment: @ThijsvanderHeijden there is no change in behaviour whether I set it to false or true, the fonts are still scaling

Comment: Hmm thats weird. What about setting ```adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth``` to false?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by scaling? The font getting larger when a smaller amount of text is entered?

Comment: @ThijsvanderHeijden by scaling I mean when the user goes to settings and in accessibility they change the font size. Even when I set adjustFontSizeToFitWidth to false. The behaviour is still the same.

Comment: Aha, so you don't want your labels to scale according to the users accessibility font settings?

Comment: @ThijsvanderHeijden Yes, I want to allow it on each label specifically. And according to the docs the default behaviour is that the fonts should not scale without setting `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory` to `true`. Which is not happening in my case right now as the font scales either way.

Comment: And if you don't use scaledFont? Just the font.

Comment: @ThijsvanderHeijden yes, that works, as I wrote in the last sentence in the description. When not using scaled font the font is not scaled. But I want to be able to use scaled font and enable and disable scaling by setting the property to true and false. I don't know what could I be doing wrong. Does anything come up to your mind?

Comment: How about using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontmetrics/2877383-scaledfontforfont?language=objc and setting a maximum size? This way the font can't scale larger than you want?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this, as I'm facing the same issue?